# Pygame missing modlues

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

Im completely new to pygame. after installing it and looking at a tutorial, the first code block i ran (from the tutorial) took me to the pygame modlule, and said that pygame.base could not be found.
it couldn't find any of these at all:

```
from pygame.base import *
from pygame.constants import *
from pygame.version import *
from pygame.rect import Rect
from pygame.compat import geterror
import pygame.rwobject
import pygame.surflock
import pygame.color
```

that's from the pygame module.

I looked in both the pygame files that were installed and saw files with those names, though i could not open them (unknown file type)

i installed the python 2.7 binary for windows version of pygame, and used the installer. everything looks like it's in the right place as far as i can tell.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem that you have pygame properly installed.  Can you even successfully run `import pygame`?

Are you sure you only have one copy of python installed?

Comment: i used the installer. i can run import pygame without issues. I have only ever attempted to download python once, and i know where all the files are.